# Why has the image upload option been changed for the UX stack exchange site.

Tags: bug, status-completed

The new interface doesnt seem to upload images half of the time and in the rare times it works, i seem to need to try several times to get it to work..

Answer (score 5):

We have a very technical term for this - it is called "a bug". It [isn't](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/170029/adding-a-picture-from-the-web-doesnt-work-on-google-chrome) just [you](https://electronics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2725/im-having-trouble-adding-images-to-a-question-using-a-mac).

It should be fixed in a couple of minutes (we're deploying currently).

Comment: Thanks Marc, was wondering what had gone wrong :)